# Remove duplicates after bulk insert exploiting ES power

Tags: python-2.7, elasticsearch, bigdata

I have an index of this type:

```
{
"email": email,
"data": {
    domain: [{
        "purchase_date": date,
        "amount": amount,
    }]
}
```

And this is the Python method I wrote, which inserts data into ES:

```
# 1: check if mail exists
mailExists = es.exists(index=index_param, doc_type=doctype_param, id=email)

# if mail does not exists => insert entire doc
if mailExists is False:
    doc = {
        "email": email,
        "data": {
            domain: [{
                "purchase_date": date,
                "amount": amount
            }]
        }
    }

    res = es.index(index=index_param, doc_type=doctype_param, id=email, body=doc)
# 2: check if already exists a domain
else:
    query = es.get(index=index_param, doc_type=doctype_param, id=email)
    # save json content into mydata
    mydata = query['_source']['data']

    # if domain exists => check if 'purchase_date' is the same as the one I'm trying to insert
    if domain in mydata:
        differentPurchaseDate = True
        for element in mydata[domain]:
            if element['purchase_date'] == purchase_date:
                differentPurchaseDate = False
        # if 'purchase_date' does not exists => add it to current domain
        if differentPurchaseDate:
            es.update(index=index_param, doc_type=doctype_param, id=email,
                 body={
                    "script": {
                        "inline":"ctx._source.data['"+domain+"'].add(params.newPurchaseDate)",
                        "params":{
                            "newPurchaseDate": {
                                "purchase_date": purchase_date, 
                                "amount": amount
                            }
                    }
                }
            })

    # add entire domain
    else:
        es.update(index=index_param, doc_type=doctype_param, id=email,
         body={
            "script": {
                "inline":"ctx._source.data['"+domain+"'] = params.newDomain",
                "params":{
                    "newDomain": [{
                        "purchase_date": purchase_date, 
                        "amount": amount
                    }]
                }
            }
        })
```

The problem is that if I use this algorithm it takes about 50 seconds for each new inserted line, but I am working with very huge file.
So, I thought: is it possible to reduce import time using a bulk insert for each file and remove duplicates after processing each file?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with parallel_bulk, [documentation here](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#elasticsearch.helpers.parallel_bulk):

```
from elasticsearch import helpers



paramL = []


# 1: check if mail exists
mailExists = es.exists(index=index_param, doc_type=doctype_param, id=email)

# if mail does not exists => insert entire doc
if mailExists is False:
    doc = {
        "email": email,
        "data": {
            domain: [{
                "purchase_date": date,
                "amount": amount
            }]
        }
    }

    ogg={
        '_op_type': 'index',
        '_index': index_param,
        '_type': doctype_param,
        '_id': email,
        '_source': doc
    }

    paramL.append(ogg)


# 2: check if already exists a domain
else:
    query = es.get(index=index_param, doc_type=doctype_param, id=email)
    # save json content into mydata
    mydata = query['_source']['data']

    # if domain exists => check if 'purchase_date' is the same as the one I'm trying to insert
    if domain in mydata:
        differentPurchaseDate = True
        for element in mydata[domain]:
            if element['purchase_date'] == purchase_date:
                differentPurchaseDate = False
        # if 'purchase_date' does not exists => add it to current domain
        if differentPurchaseDate:
             body={
                    "script": {
                        "inline":"ctx._source.data['"+domain+"'].add(params.newPurchaseDate)",
                        "params":{
                            "newPurchaseDate": {
                                "purchase_date": purchase_date, 
                                "amount": amount
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
            ogg={
            '_op_type': 'update',
            '_index': index_param,
            '_type': doctype_param,
            '_id': email,
            '_source': body
            }

            paramL.append(ogg)

    # add entire domain
    else:
         body={
            "script": {
                "inline":"ctx._source.data['"+domain+"'] = params.newDomain",
                "params":{
                    "newDomain": [{
                        "purchase_date": purchase_date, 
                        "amount": amount
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
        ogg={
        '_op_type': 'update',
        '_index': index_param,
        '_type': doctype_param,
        '_id': email,
        '_source': body
            }

        paramL.append(ogg)


for success, info in helpers.parallel_bulk(client=es, actions=paramL, thread_count=4):
    if not success: 
        print 'Doc failed', info
```

If you want to bulk also the get and the exists queries, you should use the msearch query in elastic - [documentation here](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=msearch#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.msearch) . In that case you will produce an ordered list of queries and you should change the structure of your script, because you will receive an unique output with an ordered list of results of all exists queries,or get queries, so you can't use an if -else statement as you currently use. If you will provide me more informations I will help you to implement the multi search query.

Here an example of mget query for the get queries:

```
 emails = [ <list_of_email_ID_values> ]
 results = es.mget(index = index_param,
                doc_type = doctype_param,
                body = {'ids': emails})
```

Comment: Hi @lupanoide and thank you for your suggestion.
So, after running the script I have the following error:
`for success, info in helpers.parallel_bulk(client=es, action=paramL, thread_count=4):
    TypeError: parallel_bulk() takes at least 2 arguments (2 given)`

Comment: @bit this is very strange because in this method you pass 3 arguments: client - es, action -paramL - and thread count - 4. Could you check with a print statement if one of this 3 arguments is inconsistent?

Comment: If you have just copy and paste my script , without adapting it, you have to insert the es variable es = Elasticsearch()

Comment: it works. My es var was empty and for this reason I had that error.
So, a question: in this way it took 4 hours to insert 3181378 data.
Is there a more efficient way in the perspective to insert even more data? Thanks.

Comment: yes, you can use a msearch for exists and mget for get queries and make them bulk. I will insert an example in my answer. Mind that in this way you keep in a single cycle all your queries, so you had to change your if- else condition

Comment: If you will have some problems, just ask another question appending your code here and I will help you. Could you accept my answer, please?

Comment: @bit ah, you can also play with the thread_count param in parallel_bulk query, increasing the size of the threadpool